# Pandas: row comparisons by group based on a condition across 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do row comparisons by group based on a condition across 2 columns. This condition
is: `(col1(i)-col1(j))*(col2(i)-col2(j)) <= 0`, where we are comparing every row i with row j in columns col1 and col2. If the condition is satisfied for **all** row comparisons in the group, then set true for that group, else false.

```
data = {'group':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                 'col1':[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1], 'col2':[4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

with output

```
A True
B False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)** for comparision with next row along  with **[`groupby+all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html)** for checking if all items in the group is `True`:

```
cond=((df['col1']-df['col1'].shift(-1))*(df['col2']-df['col2'].shift(-1))<=0)&(df['group']==df['group'].shift(-1))
cond.groupby(df['group']).all()
```

---

```
group
A     True
B    False
dtype: bool
```